# Not able to Read/Write Files when we changed Target API Version to 26 in Xamarin.Forms Android Application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play-services

We're using Xamarin Forms to Develop our Cross Platform Application for Android and iOS.

Since from November 2018, it is mandatory that all app packages should target to at least API 26 and if failed the app will not be uploaded to Play Store.

So while migrating to API 26 target version, we are facing a problem to read/write files to local storage.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<string> Get_SavePath(string fileName, MemoryStream stream)
{
    string root = null;
    if (Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageEmulated)
       root = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
    else
       root = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

    Java.IO.File myDir = new Java.IO.File(root + "/Signatures");
    myDir.Mkdir();
    Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(myDir, fileName);

    if (file.Exists()) file.Delete();
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream outs = new FileOutputStream(file);
        outs.Write(stream.ToArray());
        outs.Flush();
        outs.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }

    if (file.Exists())
    {
        Android.Net.Uri path = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
        string pathString = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString();
        return pathString;
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

The line `FileOutputStream outs = new FileOutputStream(file);` always give the exception **FileNotFoundException**.

So basically this only happened when we use Target Version as API 26 and if lower the Target Version it works fine.

So, keeping in mind with the Google Play Warning to target at least API level 26, we need immediate help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after searching all over the internet and reading so many articles, what helps me is to add **Runtime Permissions for Read/Write Storage Permissions**.
It was very confusing because these things were working on a lower target API level, say API 24.
Now finally I'm able to do stuffs.